# How to top align text and image in table?

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment

I am facing some problem in aligning (top-aligned) image and text in a table.

```
\documentclass[11pt,table,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=3cm,right=1cm, left=1cm, headsep=26pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}                          % End of preamble and beginning of  text.
\arrayrulecolor{gray}
\begin{center}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.0}\begin{longtable}{M{5cm}|M{6cm}|M{6cm}}
\hline
\rowcolor{gray}   
\textbf{ Col1} &  \textbf{Col2} &  \textbf{Col3} \\ \hline
 \vspace{0pt} \large{ABC} & \includegraphics[width=0.15\textheight, width=0.15\textwidth]{Europe_regions.png} \hspace{.1cm}    \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{male-female.png} &  \vspace{0pt} XYZ.  
\\ \hline   
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}             % End of document.
```

[image]

How can i top-align image and text?

Answer (score 8):

The `valign` option provided by `adjustbox` is what you're looking for:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % the demo option is just for the example
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\arrayrulecolor{gray}
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}|p{6cm}|p{6cm}}
\hline
\rowcolor{gray}
\textbf{ Col1} &  \textbf{Col2} &  \textbf{Col3} \\ \hline
\vspace{0pt}\large ABC
  & \large
  \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,valign=T]{Europe_regions.png}%
  \hspace{.1cm}%
  \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,valign=T]{male-female.png}
  &\vspace{0pt}   XYZ.
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I've simplified the input to a minimum (`longtable` is not needed to show the effect, but can be used; the `M` column type was useless).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `\belowbaseline` command of the `stackengine` package changes the baseline of stuff, including images.  In this case, setting the optional length argument to a negative number `[0pt-\heightof{X}]` moves the top edge of the main argument (the image) above the baseline (in this case by the height of the letter "X").  Recall, in the other columns, the baseline is at the bottom edge of the "ABC" and "XYZ".  Therefore, if I had set the pictures 0pt below the baseline, the tops of the images would align with the bottom of the "ABC" and "XYZ".

Note that my above comments apply to what are denoted as "short" stacks, which are the default stacktype for `stackengine`.  "Long" stacks will behave differently (see package documentation for details).

```
\documentclass[11pt,table,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=3cm,right=1cm, left=1cm, headsep=26pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}                          % End of preamble and beginning of  text.
\arrayrulecolor{gray}
\begin{center}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.0}\begin{longtable}{M{5cm}|M{6cm}|M{6cm}}
\hline
\rowcolor{gray}   
\textbf{ Col1} &  \textbf{Col2} &  \textbf{Col3} \\ \hline
 \vspace{0pt} \large{ABC} & 
 \belowbaseline[0pt-\heightof{X}]{%
   \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{Europe_regions.png}%
 }
 \hspace{.1cm}%
 \belowbaseline[0pt-\heightof{X}]{%
   \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{male-female.png}
 } &
 \vspace{0pt} XYZ.  
\\ \hline   
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}             % End of document.
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you can use the cals-tables:

[image: Top-align]

```
\documentclass[11pt,table,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=3cm,right=1cm, left=1cm, headsep=26pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{cals}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
\begin{calstable}
\makeatletter
\colwidths{{5cm}{65mm}{6cm}}
\brow
\def\cals@bgcolor{gray}\bfseries
\cell{Col1}
\cell{Col2}
\cell{Col3}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}\mdseries
\erow
\brow
\cell{\large{ABC}}
\cell{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textheight, width=0.15\textwidth]{Europe_regions.png} \hspace{.1cm}    \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{male-female.png}}
\cell{XYZ.}
\erow
\end{calstable}
\end{document}
```