# How to organize a table with multiple line cell and text in left corner?

Tags: tables, cell

I am trying to make this table organized. I want everything in the left corner of the table and the sequence as it is represented now (I want the lines in the same sequence but since I didn't know how to add a new line in each cell I had to add the text to each row and leave the left cell of the row empty). Can anyone please help me?
Thanks in advance.

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{rl}  
 \textsc{Current}  & Faculty of \textsc{Aerospace Engineering}, Master of Science \\
\textsc{Sept. 2016} & \textbf{Delft University of Technology}, Delft, Netherlands\\
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=14mm]{Delft_University_of_Technology_seal.png} &  Track: Control and Operations | Profile: Control and Simulation \\&\\ 
\textsc{Sept.} 2015 & Department of \textsc{Aerospace Engineering}, Bachelor of Science \\
\textsc{Sept.} 2011 & \textbf{Sharif University of Technology}, Tehran, Iran\\
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=14mm]{145px-Sharif_logo.svg.png} & Thesis: ``Linear Analysis on Effect of Combustion on Flame Stability \\
&in Low Swirling Flow'' | \small Advisor: Mohammad \textsc{Farshchi}\\ 
&\normalsize \textsc{Technical Gpa}: 3.92/4.00\\&\\ 
\textsc{June} 2011 & \textsc{Physics and Mathematics} School, Diploma \\ 
\textsc{Sept.} 2007 & \textbf{Farhikhtegan Pre-University and High School}, Mashhad, Iran \\
& \textsc{Overall GPA:} 4.00/4.00
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: All I am trying to do is aligning each cell of the table to the left top corner but since I have images in some of the cells it mixes up everything.

Comment: Good luck with your job applications, or "veel succes" as they would say in Delft :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or like this, with the `valign` option from `adjustbox` together with the paragraph column type `p{width}`, as in [How to top align text and image in table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124356/how-to-top-align-text-and-image-in-table). In a paragraph cell the text is automatically split between lines if necessary, and you can insert a manual linebreak with `\newline`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[t]{rp{12cm}}  
 \textsc{Current}  & Faculty of \textsc{Aerospace Engineering}, Master of Science \\
\textsc{Sept. 2016} & \textbf{Delft University of Technology}, Delft, Netherlands\\
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=14mm,valign=T]{Delft_University_of_Technology_seal.png} &  Track: Control and Operations | Profile: Control and Simulation \\&\\ 
\textsc{Sept.} 2015 & Department of \textsc{Aerospace Engineering}, Bachelor of Science \\
\textsc{Sept.} 2011 & \textbf{Sharif University of Technology}, Tehran, Iran\\
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=14mm,valign=T]{145px-Sharif_logo.png} & Thesis: ``Linear Analysis on Effect of Combustion on Flame Stability in Low Swirling Flow'' | \small Advisor: Mohammad \textsc{Farshchi}\newline\normalsize \textsc{Technical Gpa}: 3.92/4.00\\&\\ 
\textsc{June} 2011 & \textsc{Physics and Mathematics} School, Diploma \\ 
\textsc{Sept.} 2007 & \textbf{Farhikhtegan Pre-University and High School}, Mashhad, Iran \\
& \textsc{Overall GPA:} 4.00/4.00
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Like this, with `tabularx` and `makecell`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell, graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}r>{\arraybackslash}X@{}}
 \textsc{Current} & Faculty of \textsc{Aerospace Engineering}, Master of Science \\
\textsc{Sept. 2016} & \textbf{Delft University of Technology}, Delft, Netherlands\\
\makecell{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=14mm]{Delft_University_of_Technology_seal.png}} & Track: Control and Operations | Profile: Control and Simulation \\&\\
\textsc{Sept.} 2015 & Department of \textsc{Aerospace Engineering}, Bachelor of Science \\
\textsc{Sept.} 2011 & \textbf{Sharif University of Technology}, Tehran, Iran\\%
\makecell{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=14mm]{Sharif_logo}} & Thesis: ``Linear Analysis on Effect of Combustion on Flame Stability in Low Swirling Flow'' | \small Advisor: Mohammad \textsc{Farshchi}\newline
\normalsize \textsc{Technical Gpa: 3.92/4.00}\\&\\
\textsc{June} 2011 & \textsc{Physics and Mathematics} School, Diploma \\
\textsc{Sept.} 2007 & \textbf{Farhikhtegan Pre-University and High School}, Mashhad, Iran \\
& \textsc{Overall GPA:} 4.00/4.00
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With this simpler code, a nicer (in my opinion) layout:

```
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}r>{\arraybackslash}X@{}}
\multicolumn{2}{@{}>{\scshape}l@{}} {Sept. 2016\,–\,Current}\\[1ex]
\makecell{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=14mm]{Delft_University_of_Technology_seal.png}}%
 & Faculty of \textsc{Aerospace Engineering}, Master of Science \nl \textbf{Delft University of Technology}, Delft, Netherlands \nl Track: Control and Operations | Profile: Control and Simulation \\&\\
\multicolumn{2}{@{}>{\scshape}l@{}} {Sept. 2011\,–\,Sept. 2015}\\[0.5ex]
\makecell{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=14mm]{Sharif_logo}} & Department of \textsc{Aerospace Engineering}, Bachelor of Science \nl
\textbf{Sharif University of Technology}, Tehran, Iran\nl
Thesis: ``Linear Analysis on Effect of Combustion on Flame Stability in Low Swirling Flow'' | \small Advisor: Mohammad \textsc{Farshchi}\nl
\normalsize \textsc{Technical Gpa: 3.92/4.00}\\&\\
\multicolumn{2}{@{}>{\scshape}l@{}} {Sept. 2007\,–\,June 2011}\\[0.5ex]
& \textsc{Physics and Mathematics} School, Diploma \nl
\textbf{Farhikhtegan Pre-University and High School}, Mashhad, Iran \nl
\textsc{Overall GPA:} 4.00/4.00
\end{tabularx}
```

[image]