# A table, an image and a description (top aligned)

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have a similar problem to this one: [How to top align text and image in table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124356/how-to-top-align-text-and-image-in-table)

What I want is a table essentially like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GHS_hazard_pictograms#Transport_pictograms) over on Wikipedia, with an image in the first column and a textual explanation in the second column. The second column needs to be a paragraph-like column as it will have a bullet-pointed list. I would like the text to be vertically aligned with the top of the image.

My interpretation of the solution in the linked question using `valign=T` from the `adjustbox` package did not end well:

[image]

```latex
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \textbf{Label} & \textbf{Meaning} \\ \midrule
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=T]%
    {./IST_Work/Hazard_Warning_Label-Explosive} &
    \vspace{0pt}\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.5\textwidth}@{}}Explosives\end{tabular}
    \\
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=T]%
    {./IST_Work/Hazard_Warning_Label-Flammable_Gases} &
    \vspace{0pt}\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.5\textwidth}@{}}
      Flammable
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Specifically, the number~2 at the bottom (and the plain red
        background), identifies flammable gases
      \end{itemize}
    \end{tabular}
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

The issue with the second row hardly needs pointing out, but I'm not very impressed with the first row either, there is an unsightly, unnecessary grap above the image which I would prefer not to have.

## Additional info

A previous version of my table had vertically centred text in the second column. I would prefer top-aligned text anyway, but I want to mention a problem I had when I went down this path as it may be relevant. This is what I ended up with:

[image]

```latex
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \textbf{Label} & \textbf{Meaning} \\ \midrule
    \noindent\parbox{0.25\textwidth}{%
      \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]%
      {./IST_Work/Hazard_Warning_Label-Explosive}} &
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.5\textwidth}@{}}Explosives\end{tabular}
    \\
    \noindent\parbox{0.25\textwidth}{%
      \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]%
      {./IST_Work/Hazard_Warning_Label-Flammable_Gases}} &
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.5\textwidth}@{}}
      Flammable
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Specifically, the number~2 at the bottom (and the plain red
        background), identifies flammable gases
      \end{itemize}
    \end{tabular}
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

In my opinion, these images are too close together. This can be fixed very nicely with `\\[5em]` in this version. However, other solutions I experimented with could not be fixed in this way, and this fix tended to shift the text in the right hand column up a bit. Please do watch out for that, I would like to be able to add a nice little bit of white space between the rows. My current value of `\arraystretch` is 1.25.

Please note, I may need the solution to work with `longtable`, I've a feeling this table might spill onto a second page.

## MWE

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.8em}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \textbf{Label} & \textbf{Meaning} \\ \midrule
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=T]{example-image-a} &
    \vspace{0pt}\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.5\textwidth}@{}}Explosives\end{tabular}
    \\
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=T]{example-image-a} &
    \vspace{0pt}\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.5\textwidth}@{}}
      Flammable
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Specifically, the number~2 at the bottom (and the plain red
        background), identifies flammable gases
      \end{itemize}
    \end{tabular}
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To add more space between the images, you might want to have a look at the `cellspace` package and the lengths `\cellspacetoplimit` and `\cellspacebottomlimit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abd with this simpler code?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.8em}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{cp{0.5\textwidth}}
    \textbf{Label} & \textbf{Meaning} \\ \midrule
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-a} &
   Explosives
    \\ \addlinespace[2ex]
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-a} &
      Flammable
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Specifically, the number~2 at the bottom (and the plain red
        background), identifies flammable gases
      \end{itemize}
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice =) What was I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure, but I would say the nested tabulars added some vertical spacing (and some complexity in the code).

Comment: Must have been the result of earlier experiments. Thanks!