Why can't I align an image by the top border of tabular?
This is what I'm doing:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\includegraphics[width=6em,align=t]{example-image}
& THIS IS THE TEXT \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\includegraphics[width=6em,valign=t]{example-image}
& THIS IS THE TEXT \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

I'm getting:

As you see, in neither case the image is aligned by the top of the text. Why and how to fix? I'm fine with either adjustbox or graphbox, as long as one of them actually works as expected.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124369/151808

valign=t comes from adjustbox and places the baseline \ht\strutbox below the top. align=t comes from graphbox and places the baseline (36/31)ex below the top.

The align=t option (from graphbox)  36/31 of an ex as the height of the picture, as explained in footnote 5, page 5 of the manual. You should ask the author why this fraction.
To the contrary, valign=t (from adjustbox) uses the height of the strut at the current font size. Different choices by different packages.
Proof of concept:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l@{}l}
\includegraphics[width=6em,align=t]{example-image}
& \rule{4pt}{\dimeval{36ex/31}}THIS IS THE TEXT \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{l@{}l}
\includegraphics[width=6em,valign=t]{example-image}
& \rule{4pt}{\ht\strutbox}THIS IS THE TEXT \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


You can define a command that takes a supplementary argument (the highest character to which you want the picture aligned to):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\topincludegraphics}[3][]{%
  \raisebox{\dimeval{-\height+\fontcharht\font`#2}}{\includegraphics[#1]{#3}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l@{}l}
\includegraphics[width=6em,align=t]{example-image}
& \rule{4pt}{\dimeval{36ex/31}}THIS IS THE TEXT \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{l@{}l}
\includegraphics[width=6em,valign=t]{example-image}
& \rule{4pt}{\ht\strutbox}THIS IS THE TEXT \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{l@{}l}
\topincludegraphics[width=6em,valign=t]{T}{example-image}
& THIS IS THE TEXT \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}



\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\newbox\mytext\setbox\mytext\hbox{THIS IS THE TEXT}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\mytext}{\includegraphics[width=6em]{example-image}}
& THIS IS THE TEXT \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


